# programmatic vs static broadcast receivers in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, manifest, google-cloud-messaging

In my app, I am utilizing GCM and push notifications.
However, I am a bit concerned regarding broadcast receivers.
In the app, I see the broadcast receivers are being declared 2 types.

1. static via the manifest

   ```
      <receiver
       android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
           <category android:name="com.myapp" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   ```
2. programmatic inside activity

   ```
      private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);

       WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       WakeLocker.release();
   }  };
   ```

My questions are as follows:

***QUESTION 1:*** Can we remove the programmatic declaration of broadcast receiver and still get a totally valid notification ? if yes, is the reason because we have it in the manifest already ?

***QUESTION 2:*** If the receiver is declared both static and programmatic, which one is called when ? Which one has the priority ? If the app is open and running the programmatic one gets called ?  and in case the app is not running, the static one ?

Answer (score 2):

Question #1 makes no sense to me, sorry.

> If the receiver is declared both static and programmatic, which one is called when ?

If they both have `IntentFilter`s that match the same broadcast, they both will receive the broadcast. For regular broadcasts, the order in which they will receive the broadcast is indeterminate.

> Which one has the priority ?

For regular broadcasts, neither have "the priority" -- both get the broadcast, and you have no way of knowing who gets it first (and on multi-core devices, they could get the broadcast at the same time, in theory). Ordered broadcasts allow you to control priority of delivery, and only one of your receivers will get the ordered broadcast at a time.

> If the app is open and running the programmatic one gets called ?

If "the app is open and running" means that you have your receiver registered via `registerReceiver()` *and* the manifest, then they both receive the broadcast.

> and in case the app is not running, the static one ?

If "not running" means that you have unregistered your receiver that you registered via `registerReceiver()`, then only the receiver registered in the manifest will receive the broadcast.

Comment: which one you suggest to use ? the static or the programmatic?

Comment: @tony9099: That is impossible to answer in the abstract. Usually only one will be a practical solution for a given circumstance.